# how to map a row in temp table in asp.net (Vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, mapping

I have a temp table and i want to map data from it like we can in sql e.g "Select name from tablName where name=@name" . I want to do same thing in asp.net(vb.net) code behind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some code, how the data table is declared n all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked how to use select statement in code behind. so i got answer is:-

```
 string sqlFilter = "Id = '" + userid + "'";
  DataRow[] data = dt.Select(sqlFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ram Singh: Suppose your temp table is like bellow one

```
Create Table #temp( Name varchar(250) )
```

your select query will be like this

```
Select Name from #temp WHERE Name = @name
```

Comment: sir it is in sql and i m asking in vb.net.

Comment: reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()    
if reader.Read() then '' <<<<< newly inserted code
    result = reader.GetString("Name")
end if

reader.GetString("Name")  Name will be the column name in temporary table.